# Proof Question involving subspaces in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Suppose that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ . Prove that if
>   $\dim U + \dim W > \dim V$,
>   then $U \cap W \neq \{0\}.$

How can I go about proving this? I know the identity that:

- $\dim( U + W) + \dim (U ∩ W) = \dim(U) + \dim(W)$ 
  , since $U$ and $W$ are both subspaces of $V$ but I'm not too sure how to approach this.
  Any help would be appreciated.
  Thanks.

Comment: How big can $\dim(U+W)$ possibly be?

Comment: I think there is something missing because **every** subspace $S$ has $0 \in S$ so any two subspaces **always** have non empty intersection regardless of dimensions.

Comment: @copper.hat $U \cap W \neq 0$ is not the same as $U \cap W \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @user3482749: Perhaps they meant $\{0\}$...

Comment: Show that if $V \cap W$ is trivial, $v \in V$, $w \in W$ and $v+w = 0$ then $v=w=0$. Then suppose $v_i,w_j$ are bases for $V,W$ respectively. Show that the combination $v_i,w_j$ is linearly independent and so $\dim U + \dim V \le \dim V$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that is the usual notation.

Comment: @user3482749: Perhaps, but in over 3 decades I have rarely seen $0$ used to denote the trivial subspace.

Comment: I can't, off hand, think of a linear algebra (or module theory, or representation theory, or homological algebra, or anything else that has a need to talk about such things) textbook that doesn't use such notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the Grassmann formula, just supplement it with the last inequality below:
$$
\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)=\dim(U+W)\le\dim V
$$
Then you can immediately deduce that
$$
\dim(U\cap W)\ge\dim U+\dim W-\dim V
$$
and, in your case,
$$
\dim(U\cap W)>0
$$

Answer (score 1):

One could go about it by proving the contrapositive.

> Prove that if $(U \cap W) = \lbrace \mathbf{0} \rbrace$, then $\text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) \leq \text{dim}(V)$.

*Proof suggestion*:

> Let us assume $(U \cap W) = \lbrace \mathbf{0} \rbrace$. We know that if $(U \cap W) = \lbrace \mathbf{0} \rbrace$, then $\text{dim}(U \cap W) = 0$. We also know that $\text{dim}(U + W) \leq \text{dim}(V)$. If we combine these two, we get that
>   $$
> \text{dim}(U + W) + \text{dim}(U \cap W) \leq \text{dim}(V).
> $$
>   Since we also know that $\text{dim}(U + W) + \text{dim}(U \cap W) = \text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W)$, this is the same as
>   $$
> \text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) \leq \text{dim}(V).
> $$

Let us now assume that $\text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) > \text{dim}(V)$. If so, then it can't be the case that $(U \cap W) = \lbrace \mathbf{0} \rbrace$, because that would imply $\text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) \leq \text{dim}(V)$. We can then conclude that $(U \cap W) \neq \lbrace \mathbf{0} \rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis $\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)=\dim U+\dim W>\dim V$. If $U\cap W=\emptyset$ then $\dim(U\cap W)=0$ then $\dim(U+W)>\dim V$, absurd because $U+W$ is a subspace of $V$ then $\dim(U+W)\leq \dim V$. Therefore, $U\cap W\neq\emptyset$.